# Adding items to a QComboBox adds blank items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I am adding items to a **QComboBox** through a **for cycle** which is within a function that is called by pressing a button. As you can see in the code below I am calling data from a database, specifically from **SQLite**, which is filtered through a variable, this is: *depid*. The function performs well when called and fills in the respective **QComboBox**, but when called again, although it still keeps the respective elements, it adds a blank item, when I press the button again, the **QComboBox** keeps the elements, keeps the previous blank item and adds another, that is, each time I call the function adds a blank item.

```
Cur.execute("SELECT * FROM workers WHERE departament = "+str(depid))
workfilter = Cur.fetchall()

for n,data in enumerate(workfilter):
    self.BoxFilteredWorer.addItem("")
    self.BoxFilteredWorer.setItemText(n, data[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

The `addItem(s)` method add new item with text "s" in the final position and `setItemText(i, s)` replaces the text of the ith item with "s".

To understand the error I will use the following example: let's say that on the first click 3 items with empty text are added and they are set as text "a", "b" and "c" of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd item, respectively, in the second click 3 new items with empty text will be added so there will be 6 items: "a", "b", "c", "", "" and "" but you replace the 1st, 2nd and 3rd with 3 texts "x", "y" and "z" so in the end there would be the 6 items: "x", "y", "z", "", "" y "".

#### Solution:

It is not necessary to use `addItem()` with `setItemText()`, just clean the QComboBox before the loop and add new items, in addition the enumerate is not necessary.

On the other hand do not use concatenation to create an SQL query since it makes your code susceptible to SQL Injection, instead use placeholders.

```py
Cur.execute("SELECT * FROM workers WHERE departament = ?", (depid,))
workfilter = Cur.fetchall()

self.BoxFilteredWorer.clear()
for data in workfilter:
    self.BoxFilteredWorer.addItem(data[1])
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you. What happens with the enumerate function is that I saw it in a tutorial and well, as it worked, I left it so, according to the tutorial was to determine the index of each item, I'm quite new in PyQt5.  Another thing, how would that query be improved? Using that placeholders method you mention.

Comment: @Jalkhov 1) Do not just copy code, understand it and analyze why it works and in which cases it may fail. 2) The placeholders are the "?" for what you already apply, read https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/